# I am Connecting to data Base After Making Jar File in java But "ClassNotFoundException" after making jar file Below is code

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc, jdbc-odbc

Here IS Code Any Suggestions When i am trying to access the data base
it shows error after making jar file

```
   File f = new File("E:\\DB\\**\\***.mdb");
                    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver").newInstance();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Driver loded succesfully");
                    String database = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ="+f.getAbsolutePath();
                    connection = DriverManager.getConnection( database ,"",""); 

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "connection is"+connection);

                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"erroris"+ e);;
                }
```

Comment: Don't you thing it might be a good idea to include the error here? There is a LOT that can go wrong in that code snippet. Do you have the ODBC driver in your classpath? Is that the real filename you're using?

Comment: Have your application display the result returned by `System.getProperty("java.version")`. What does it say?

Comment: Yes i am using real File name

Comment: System.getProperty("") same error

Comment: The point of displaying `System.getProperty("java.version")` is not to fix the problem with your application, it is to show the version of Java you are running when the application fails. (Hint: If your application is running under Java 8 then the JDBC-ODBC Bridge is not available and your code simply will not work.)

Comment: No i am using old version which had facility of JDBC-ODBC

Comment: Are you sure that your JAR file is running under the same version of Java as when your application is running in Eclipse? Eclipse could be running the code under Java 7 (if that is the JRE specified in the Eclipse settings), while the JAR file could be running under Java 8 (if that is the default JRE registered with the operating system).

Comment: Yes its JAVA(version) Compatibility issue issue Thanks for Help :) Gord Thompson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its Only java Compatibility Issue . ODBC connection is not available in new versions of Java . So it work on old version on which i made. Thanks to
@Gord Thompson

Answer (score 0):

`ClassNotFoundException` means that your program can't find the `odbc` driver class, try including the jar file in your path.

Comment: When I use this code eclipse it worked properly but just not in jar file